# No suitable injection token for parameter 'width' of class 'RectangleComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token

Tags: angular, constructor

I trying to build a simple component using StackBlitz Angular. But I keep getting an error: No suitable injection token for parameter 'width' of class 'RectangleComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token. And in console: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Number -> Number -> Number]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Number! This is the code so far, but I can't even start, because I'm supposed to use constructor as : `

```
class Rectangle 
{ 
height:number; 
width: number; 
constructor(height:number, width:number){
this.height = height; this.width = width;
}
}`
```

This is what I have so far, trying workarounds.... ```

````
@Component({
  selector: 'rectangle',
  templateUrl: './rectangle.component.html',
  styles: [{ font-family: Lato; }],
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RectangleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  height: number;
  width: number;

  constructor(@Inject(Number) height: number, width: number) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('hello bobby');
  }
}```
````

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this component? @Inject(Number) doesn't make much sense here. Also, you don't need to pass the height and width properties to the Component's constructor.

Comment: "because I'm supposed to use constructor"? Why? Also I think you're confusing constructors with dependency injection with regard to your component. Check out [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

Comment: I'm building on pre-existing code. adding this function: findArea(height: number, width: number) {
    const area = height * width;
    if (height === width) {
      return console.log('this is a square ' + area);
    } else {
      return console.log('this is a rectangle ' + area);
    }
  }

Comment: going to use inputs and ngModel to modify height and width. I agree with both of you - when the constructor is empty and used just on @Input() it works fine. I was wondering if there was something specific I had to do to remove the injection token error and keep the constructor that I've been instructed to use